# Rails 5 Could not find table ''

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After setup the act_as_follower gem

and properly added the button_link on user view show and configure the routes and the controller

Rails spits out this error about did not find table ¨ and did not specify which table.

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#follow Could not
>   find table ''

just point to **current_user.follow(@user)** on users controller.

Someone have any idea about this issue?

```
def follow
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])

    if current_user == @user
    flash[:error] = 'You cannot follow yourself.'
  else
  current_user.follow(@user)
end
end
```

Comment: did you run the migrations for `acts_as_follower`?

Comment: yes i did. thats why is a strange behavior

Comment: does restarting your Rails server help?

Comment: Sorry guys i forget to mention that iḿ using rails 5 so. that was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK my mistake on rails 5 you need to use the master branch

```
gem 'acts_as_follower', github: 'tcocca/acts_as_follower', branch: 'master'
```